# How to unit test C# code that's expected to fail compilation for negative testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, compilation, strong-typing

We're meant to generate a string output that's required to adhere to a particular set of syntactical rules. I created an object model in order to enforce that syntax via C#'s strong-typing with the intent to prevent the possibility of generating invalid output.

I can create positive tests, i.e. valid C# generating valid output. What I'm unable to do is run negative tests, i.e. ensuring that attempting to generate invalid output will throw errors at compilation.

Explicit example:

```
namespace Abstract
{
    public interface FooType { }
    public interface FooString : FooType { }
}
```

```
public interface Integer : Abstract.FooType { }    
public interface SingleLine : Abstract.FooString { }
public interface MultiLine : Abstract.FooString { }

public class Bar<T>
    where T : Abstract.FooType
{
    public Bar(string s) {
        // do stuff with s and T, where T is SingleLine or MultiLine
    }

    public Bar(int i) {
        // do stuff with i and T, where T is Integer
    }
}

public static class Foo
{
    public static Bar<T> Bar<T>(int i) where T : Integer {
        return new Bar<T>(i);
    }

    public static Bar<SingleLine> Bar(string s) {
        return new Bar<SingleLine>(s);
    }

    public static Bar<T> Bar<T>(string s) where T : Abstract.FooString {
        return new Bar<T>(s);
    }
}
```

All of that just so I can do:

```
Foo.Bar<SingleLine>("some string");  // ok
Foo.Bar("another string");           // ok
Foo.Bar<MultiLine>("more\nstrings"); // still ok
Foo.Bar<Integer>(24)                 // also ok

// How to test these lines for compilation failure?
Foo.Bar<Integer>("no good");
Foo.Bar<MultiLine>(-1);
```

In case it matters, I'm using VS2012 Express for Desktop.

Comment: You mean, testing that a particular use is rejected by the compiler?

Comment: Perhaps if you can add an example to your question of what such uncompilable code might be?

Comment: If your code does not compile you cannot test it. So the compiler will test your code for syntax errors. And you only do unit tests for the runtime part.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever added example

Comment: Your example looks like a unit test for the C# compiler, not for your code. What kind of mistake to you want to detect with this test?

Comment: You could feed it into the CodeDom and then look for a compilation error?

Comment: In some situations you can use reflection to check if classes conform to certain conventions/rules. But I doubt that's what you should use here.

Comment: What is the point of this?  What exactly are you going to do when the unit test fails?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Data is being passed in markup, e.g. `<Data Type="Integer">513</Data><Data Type="SingleLine">blah<Data>`, but with multiple data types and other arbitrary rules, e.g. `<Contains><Data Type="<SomeStringTypeOnly>">FindThis</Data></Contains>` (no integer types). Devs have been writing this data in code with a ton of in-place static string manipulation. `Foo` would be dynamic, strongly-typed, more readable, etc.

Comment: @HansPassant I want the compiler to error if the code is going to generate string data that's going to cause the framework to error out or fail anyway. (Btw, must use framework, not an option.)

Comment: I made some changes, @HansPassant, is it still difficult to tell what I'm trying to ask?

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me, I'm facing the exact same issue and would have loved to make a simple unit test that succeeds when it can't be compiled.  The cost/benefit ratio of having to set up a CodeDom installation to check it is a little stiff at this point, but would certainly be a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, just craft the code snippet that you want to fail to compile (as a string, or load a .cs file into a string) and invoke the C# compiler on it using the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx).  Your test then just needs to check that the compiler failed, and if you like check the line number error message etc... is correct.

Of course this is a fair amount of effort - you need to evaluate how much gain this is really going to get you.  If you are developing some sort of API that other developers are going to use, and this is an important feature that may well inadvertantly break in the future through some subtle change then you may want to unit test this.  Otherwise this is probably going to be a lot of effort for little reward (IMO).

Comment: Yeah... good point about the effort/reward consideration

Answer (score 4):

I'd be highly suspect of code that did this.  But, if you wanted to create a unit test to make sure someone didn't change code to allow a class to work in a certain way (i.e. stop having a compile error when used in a certain way, you could use the CodeDOM in this way:

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mydll.dll");

parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

CompilerResults results = 
    icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, 
        String.Format(@"using System;

namespace Testing
{{
    class Program
    {{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {{
            {0}
            Console.ReadLine();
        }}
    }}
}}
", "Foo.Bar<Integer>("no good");"));
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, results.Errors.Count);
```

You basically create a provider, tell it you want to reference a particular DLL (presumably where `Foo` is) then create the code (text--note I'm doubling up the curly brackets because they're delimiters in `String.Format`) you want to test, wrapped in a class (including `Main` if you're generating an exe) then compile the text.  You can verify that an error occurred with the `Errors` collection.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably noticed, for a unit test to run, its code will have to be compiled succesfully, so it's a bit a chicken-egg problem.

You can solve this by calling the API using reflection. The CLR will throw an exception if you are calling a type in a way that is not compatible (for instance when you used type constraints).

Another option is to use [Code Dom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) (or just trigger the csc.exe) using a piece of text in your unit test. You can make your test pass by letting the compilation fail.

Comment: Reflection is also a chicken-egg thing, you need to compile code first before you can reflect on it.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: It depends. If you can to check whether code that consumes your API can compile, you can use reflection on that. Of course the API must be able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

[Roslyn](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685) will let you do stuff like this. It will probably be built in to .net 5, or C# 6 or something. It's essentially equivalent to code dom though.